# Getting an error when linking contact form in html i have tried everything

Tags: html

```
    <nav class="Navbar">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href=“index.html”>Home</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href=“contact.html”>About</a></li>
            <li>
                <a href=“Services.html”>Services</a></li>

            <li>
                <a href=“Contact.html”>Contact</a></li>
```

This is the error i get

> Cannot GET /%E2%80%9CContact.html%E2%80%9D

Comment: Replace the the quotes (`“` and `”`) with regular double quotation marks.(`"`).

Answer (score 0):

The contact form you saved as "contact.html", check that the page can load independently and please check if it is saved in same folder as your document. You might want to get its src/ folder.

Answer (score -1):

close your `</ul>` and `</nav>`

check your link and learn about relative and absolute links. a url will solve that problem if it is remote. if its local, make sure its not in a different directory.

check this page out

https://www.coffeecup.com/help/articles/absolute-vs-relative-pathslinks/

i bet one of those 2 things helps. keep us posted